# Order List of objects considering another List C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

How can I solve this problem? I was trying with LINQ but I'm not finding a way.

I have two Lists:

1. List of object File (in `System.IO`)
2. List of string (built in type)

The first List contains x numbers of File objects.
The second list contains x numbers of string representing extensions, an example would be `{".txt",".exe"}`.
I need to have File objects with the property Extension contained in the second List before others File objects.
A most detailed example would be:

1) List has these File objects:

```
File {Name="1" Extension = ".exe"}
File {Name="2" Extension = ".txt"}
File {Name="3" Extension = ".ini"}
File {Name="4" Extension = ".exe"}
File {Name="5" Extension = ".zip"}
File {Name="6" Extension = ".jpg"}
```

2) List has these values: {".txt",".exe"}

The ordered List would be:

```
File {Name="1" Extension =".exe"}
File {Name="2" Extension =".txt"}
File {Name="4" Extension =".exe"}
...Remaining
File
Objects, doesn't matter the position.
```

LINQ that I've tried:

```
var sorted = files.OrderBy(cus => precedenceExstensions.Contains(cus.Extension));
```

Comment: Show what you tried in LINQ, so we can tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: Your question is essentially a _set of requirements_ thus making it too broad.

Comment: var sorted = files.OrderBy(cus => precedenceExstensions.Contains(cus.Extension)); I was thinking of resolve the problem without LINQ because it's much easier .. But I will need to create some temporary variables making the code complicated and much different then simply LINQ

Answer (score 0):

You want to order by descending:

```
files.OrderByDescending(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension));
```

Linq will order the boolean `false` before `true`, and you want them in the opposite order.

Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class File
{
    public string Name;
    public string Extension;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("File: {0}, Extension: {1}", Name, Extension);
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var files = new List<File>()
        {
            new File {Name="1", Extension = ".exe"},
            new File {Name="2", Extension = ".txt"},
            new File {Name="3", Extension = ".ini"},
            new File {Name="4", Extension = ".exe"},
            new File {Name="5", Extension = ".zip"},
            new File {Name="6", Extension = ".jpg"}
        };

        var extensions = new[]{".txt", ".exe"};


        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", files.OrderByDescending(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension))));
    }
}
```

You can see it on dotnetfiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wn7PcK).